# How to buffer bytes for seconds and then send them

Tags: java, android

I have a function in a media process class like this:

```
    public void encode(bytes[] data) {
            // process the data and then send to RTMP server
    }
```

This function will be called several times per second. I need to buffer the bytes for 5 seconds, and then send it. If create `Timer` or `Thread` in the function, it will be too memory-wasted. Is there a better way to achieve the goal?

Comment: i think you should buffer for size not time.

Comment: @MoshErsan I know the requirement is weird... I use a RTMP API without video/sound synchronization, so I need to control the time when audio data being sent

Comment: so this is not RTMP, its just uploading files :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

public void encode(byte[] data) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0 >= 5000) {
        t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // process the data and then send to RTMP server
    } else {
        // buffer data
    }
}
```

Comment: If no more data comes, then wont this data just sit there?

Comment: I need the data being sent 5 seconds after arriving, not the whole buffer being sent every 5 seconds. A bit like keeping a 5 seconds length queue.

Answer (score 1):

You should already be doing this `sending` in a thread, so why not simply call `sleep(5000);`

Comment: I will try this approach and evaluate the performance later, thank you